# Can I copy and use the mdf files using Sql Server Express?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, sql-server-express

I'm making an asp.net web application and I'm thinking about binding it with sql server express edition 2008 R2, so I would like to copy the database file and deploy it with the application. Is this possible with this version?

What problems can I expect to have with this dbms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes. Here's a link describing some of the benefits of doing so: http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/5063.aspx

Additionally, the comments continue to show how to work with the database in that folder, and show how to configure the connectionstring.

The primary value to regard is the one for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.attachdbfilename.aspx